# Compare dates with prefixing strings Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In an Excel spreadsheet, I have 2 columns.

Column 1:
[image: Dates in DD/MM/YYYY format]

And in column 2, similar data but unfortunately, each date is prefixed with somebody's initials followed by a space. Like so:
[image: DD/MM/YYYY dates with initials prefixing]

On top of that, somebody may have more than one middle name, causing an extra letter.

I need to compare each date from column 2 against it's counterpart in column 1. If the Col2 date is after Col1 date, I need to highlight the cell. I will use the 'Use formula for conditional highlighting' option.

How can I achieve this using an Excel formula? I may have hundreds of columns, each one needs to follow the formula.

Comment: Would each column need to be compared to the column before that one or would it always be compared to column 1?

Comment: @JvdV Not an absolute reference. Each row from column 2 would be compared with the parallel row from 1. Meaning, the field in row 3 (Col 2) would be compared against row 3 (Col 1)

Comment: I understand, but would the rows of column 3 be compared to column 2 or column 1. You say you may have hundred or more columns

Comment: are the dates in column one and excel serial date or are they a date in string format?  By default strings are left justified like your column 1 example, where a number (excel serial date) would be right justified by date.  you can test this with `=isnumber(A1)` where A1 is any date in column 1.  This may affect potential answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you an idea:

*Sample data:*

[image]

- Select column B
- Insert new formatting rule, through formula:

  ```
  =DATEVALUE(RIGHT($B1,10))>$A1
  ```
- Apply formatting to the rule.

*Example data:*

[image]

In case you need to test all columns against the first column, highlight all other columns and insert the following rule:

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1)),10))>$A1
```

[image]

Comment: Be aware that `datevalue` can be rather finicky at times and will not always properly process dates.

Comment: @ForwardEd, but we need to know if the date is actuallly larger than column 1. I find it hard to visualize this working and am a bit reluctant to recreate the sample data :).

Comment: You are 100% correct.  My mind blanked and I thought you need to find exact matches for some reason.